# Combine Holo Theme and Custom Title - AndroidRuntimeException

Tags: android, titlebar, android-theme

In my app I'm using the normal Theme with a custom title (with a background that changes color dynamically, logo and text). I would like to use, for the supported devices, the Holo Theme. I'm a bit lost btw..

Is the Holo theme supported before Android 3.0 (I suppose no)?

For this reason I would like to keep my app like this for the previous versions of Android and use the HoloTheme with the new ones.
I've created a dir values-v14 and added there a themes.xml using the Holo.Theme.
By the way this is not working, because I've got a RuntimeException:

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
```

My custom title is defined in a xml file, and then called like this:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);
```

Is it also possible to modify the ActionBar dinamically as am I doing with my custom title?

Thanks.